# Workdir of Node.JS

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile from nodejs. I'm copying the right folders (which are in my repo after a npm install) and I start the node.js server.
It seems to work fine but what I don't understand is `/usr/src/www`.
I saw it often on the internet. But is it important in which directory you're running your server.js?

```
FROM node

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/www
WORKDIR /usr/src/www

# copy
COPY node_modules /usr/src/www/node_modules
COPY gulpfile.js /usr/src/www/gulpfile.js
COPY gulp.config.js /usr/src/www/gulp.config.js
COPY server.js /usr/src/www/server.js 

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In node.js all the references are relative to the file which you reference from. So usually the working dir is less relevent

Comment: Is it also not relevant when you also have a nginx-container where you have to proxy the nodeJS (with some static code as angular) in nginx.conf